# How are scheduled Python programs typically ran?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

Let's say I want to run some function once a day at 10 am.

- Do I simply keep a script running in the background forever?
- What if I don't want to keep my laptop open/on for many days at a time?
- Will the process eat a lot of CPU?

Are the answers to these questions different if I use cron/launchd vs scheduling programmatically? Thanks!

Comment: For unix-like systems you would use something like [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [systemd timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html).  For Windows, I'm sure there are similar schedulers.

Comment: The answer to the CPU question really depends what your script is doing.

Comment: @cricket_007, I guess OP means whether the program consumes CPU time if the scheduling is implemented by means of `time.sleep(24 * 60 * 60)`.

Comment: @Kay Sure, I meant something like opening/creating resources without closing them.

Comment: @larsks But how do they work exactly? Is there something that's constantly running in the background and can I put my computer to sleep if I still want the script to run on schedule?

Comment: And yes, @cricket_007 I meant will keeping the script constantly running eat up CPU, even if it's sleeping for the majority of the time

Comment: For my example, the `cron` daemon or `systemd` are constantly running the background.  In most cases, if your computer is asleep, nothing will run.

Comment: @larsks: Windows does indeed have a similar system called "task scheduler", and it does have an option to wake the machine from sleep. But I guess the question is mainly about unix-like systems since it mentions cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question will likely depend on your platform, the available facilities and your particular project needs.

First let me address system resources. If you want to use the fewest resources, just call `time.sleep(NNN)`, where NNN is the number of seconds until the next instance of 10AM.  `time.sleep` will suspend execution of your program and should consume zero (or virtually zero resources). The python GC may periodically wake up and do maintenance, but it's work should be negligible.

If you're on Unix, `cron` is the typical facility for scheduling future tasks. It implements a fairly efficient Franta–Maly event list manager. It will determine based on the list of tasks which will occurr *next* and sleep until then.

On Windows, you have the Schedule Manager. It's a Frankenstein of complexity -- but it's incredibly flexible and can handle running missed events due to power outages and laptop hibernates, etc...